# Spark coalesce performance

Tags: apache-spark

Now for my application , I find it has significant performance difference depend on the shuffle parameter of coalesce.

```scala
val subscriber = a.join(b).map(x=>(x._1,x_2))
// subscriber' partition number is above 40000
subscriber.coalesce(5,true).saveAsTextFile("result") // performance good
subscriber.coalesce(5,false).saveAsTextFile("result") // performance poor
```

According to Spark Document of coalesce,

> However, if you're doing a drastic coalesce, e.g. to numPartitions = 1, this may result in your computation taking place on fewer nodes than you like (e.g. one node in the case of numPartitions = 1). To avoid this, you can pass shuffle = true. This will add a shuffle step, but means the current upstream partitions will be executed in parallel (per whatever the current partitioning is).

But I can't understand why  this may result in your computation taking place on fewer nodes if I don't set shuffle=true. Can someone explain it ?

Comment: Same problem.  But spark 1.6.1 does't have the problem. In spark 2.0.2, coalesce is very slow.